# Вывод переменной в середине текста MessageBox

Tags: c++, строки, winapi, visual-c++, указатели

В `char WindowText[4096]` хранится заголовок окна (не окна с сообщением), полученный при помощи `GetWindowText`. Когда я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
MessageBoxA(0, "Window Text = '"+ WindowText +"'! Some Text", "Some Title", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
```

То получаю: [image: Ошибка вывода]
И:

[image: Ошибка вывода 2]

Что делать?

Comment: А Вы не пробовали `Window Text` написать одним словом и без пробела? Так, как указано в объявлении `char WindowText[4096]`...

Comment: Это я при копипасте сюда ошибку сделал, сейчас поправлю , в коде всё верно, но не работает

Comment: Тогда вторая возможная (в смысле, это точно проблема, но не факт что последняя ;-) ) проблема - Вы уверены, что можете складывать строки (константную и массив символов) вот таким образом? Вы перегружали для этого операцию сложения? Обычно так нельзя делать. На вопрос что делать - сформируйте строку ДО этого вызова либо каким-то snprintf() либо еще как (да хоть через строку STL С++).

Comment: Я не уверен ни в чём. Просто мне нужно вставить между ' ' тайтл окна - WindowText. Когда я делаю это привычным для меня образом, то получаю ошибки.

Comment: `С++ != С# && != Java` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал так:

> ```
> sprintf(Message, "%s%s%s", "Window Text = '", WindowText +"'! Some Text");
> MessageBoxA(0, Message, "Some Title", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
> ```

Но можно делать также как и в других ответах.

Всем большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Например, вот как-нибудь так:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::string sl;

    char WindowText[4096] = "***";
    sl = "Window Text = '";
    sl += WindowText;
    sl += "'! Some Text";

    MessageBoxA(0, sl.c_str(), "Some Title" ,MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);     
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD:** По просьбе коллеги немного дополню ответ. Раз в вопросе был указан тег С++, то я привожу пример с наиболее простыми конструкциями из этого языка с максимальным сохранением сущностей из вопроса (конечно, лучше было бы все строки заменить на тип `std::string`). И естественно, это не единственно возможный вариант.

В С++ для пользовательских типов данных, и в частности, для классов и структур, можно переопределять  (перегружать) поведение стандартных операций. В случае с классом `string` из стандартной библиотеки шаблонов, оператор `+` (и `+=`) переопределен для конкатенации таких строк с объектами такого же типа и со строками в стиле языка Си. Чтобы компилятор мог воспользоваться этим перегруженным оператором необходимо, чтобы хотя бы один из двух операндов принадлежал этому типу `string`.

Если же оставаться в рамках стандартной библиотеки языка Си, то можно было воспользоваться уже упомянутыми мной в комментариях функциями для формирования строки `sprintf()/snprintf()`, упомянутыми Harry функциями для конкатенации строк `strcat()/strncat()` и даже функциями для копирования/перемещения строк `strcpy()/strncpy()/memcpy()/memmove()`. Предпочтение следует отдавать тем вариантам функций, где в именах есть буква `n` (это не касается `memcpy()/memmove()`, т.к. в них тоже надо явно указывать размер) - эти функции, как бы (в смысле предоставляют возможность, а остальное зависит от программиста), защищены от ошибок переполнения, поскольку нужно явно указывать размер целевого блока памяти.

Answer (score 2):

В С/С++ конкатенация строк с помощью знака `+` имеет смысл, если это строки типа `string`. Если это C-сроки (как ваши литералы типа `"Window Text = '"` или переменная `WindowText`, объявленная как массив `char`), то они интерпретируются как *указатели* на первые символы, а суммирование указателей - нонсенс, о чем вам и поведал компилятор.

Для этого нужно использовать функции наподобие `strcpy`, `strcat` и иже с ними. Например,

```
char buf[5120] = "Window Text = '";
strcat(buf, WindowText);
strcat(buf,"'! Some Text");
MessageBoxA(0, buf, ....
```